# Inverse gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, inverse, gamma-distribution

How to implement inverse gamma distribution function in R?

I tried with the package Laplaces Demons, but it gives me the error: "Warning message:
package ‘LaplacesDemon’ was built under R version 3.3.3 ".

Thanks.

Comment: Why you can't update your R?

Comment: They are very simple to implement; you should consider doing it yourself. Keep in mind that if x is distributed according to a gamma with some shape and rate parameters, 1/x is distributed according an inverse gamma with the same parameters. You can generate sample from inverse gamma using `rgamma` and calculate the density directly from the definition.